# JQuery Mobile bind event to listview

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a vclick to a dynamic JQM listview.  But I can not figure out how to identify which number is being clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/2hR9w/

```
for (var x=0; x<2; x++ ) {
    $("#listitem"+x).bind("vclick",function(e)
           { console.log("clicked"+x); });
    console.log(x);
}
```

​

Something is wrong with the code, but i can't figure out why x is always the max loop value, since I feel like it should be set at the time of the loop.

it always reads clicked2, never clicked1.

Comment: Can you check the fiddle and make sure you submitted the right one? I don't see any reference to `X` in the code, and I always get `clicked1`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, just updated.  It was wrong

Comment: Well... It's still the same fiddle...

Comment: kinda new at fiddle, thought update would update it. http://jsfiddle.net/2hR9w/

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/2hR9w/1/ (I changed it to `click` so I could test on my desktop.)

Comment: your awesome!  Thank you, thats perfect

Comment: I overselected to show you how you could be real specific. [There's several selectors to choose from](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: that starts with selector is going to be hugely helpful.  I was not thinking of it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2hR9w/7/

The value is being reported as "2" all the time, because when the click-event runs, the value IS 2.....It has reached the end of the assignment for-loop.

You don't need the loop at all - see the attached fiddle.

Comment: what is strange for me, is that it is a local variable, so im not sure why it even exists when the function is run.  Do you know?  Thank you for your response

Comment: Check this article - view the "Infamous Loop Problem" a few screens down.... http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/